# cheap temperature sensors with bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, sensor

I have a PI and I need to develop an application to sense between 8 to 16 temperature sensors.

1. BMP180 and a multiplexer have been a PITA and I havent been able to make it work.
2. Is there any other way like: BLE sensors (but cheap), I developed a BLE app with Node.js and it was very simple.
3. Or maybe a multiplexer with an SDK already tested?

Comment: Not an answer because it's unclear what you've tried in terms of "multiplexing" but the usual way to do this is via something like i2c. There are a few tutorials about the specific case of sensors connected with i2c and the Pi. Is there something about this approach that doesn't meet your requirements?

Comment: Have you looked at using ds18b20's and 1-wire  instead? They are cheap and easy to read several at once, connected by just 1 wire. Check https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-11-ds18b20-temperature-sensing/hardware for more info on this.